# Filter AdSense Report by Site Name using Management API

Tags: api, filter, adsense

Is there a way to create a filter using site name? I have looked in here and many other sites but could not find the desired filter: https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/reporting/filtering?hl=en

This is site filter in AdSense front-end:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured **DOMAIN_NAME** dimension can be used to filter on a specific site.

Answer (score 1):

@jisu your answer is correct. You should try to mark that or this as the answer so we can close this.

For others who would encounter this, you can use the following code, remember to use 2 equal signs

```
filter=['AD_CLIENT_ID==' + ad_client_id , 'DOMAIN_NAME==' + site ]
```